# Visual Studio Code mssql extension won't connect to the server

Tags: sql-server, macos, visual-studio-code

Ok, so the problem is VSCode won't connect to the server, mssql extension is installed.

I have used **localhost** as the server name, tried with Integrated login, wouldn't connect. Tried with SQL Login, with User Name **SA** and **sa**, and passwords **""**, **"sql"**, **"SQL"**. Used all combinations.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on? Is there something I have to set up before I start connecting to the server?

Comment: " wouldn't connect." - I'm guessing there's an error message, what does it say?

Comment: 1st is wouldn't connect with information provided. Asks for a retry.
2nd is very long but basically says that server was not found or isn't accessible. I'm guessing the credentials are wrong

Comment: I mean, it doesn't seem like you know the password to be honest.

Comment: Honestly, I don't. Microsoft docs say to log in with SA username but they don't say the password. I've seen somewhere that it's "" but that's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I use the **mssql** extension with **VSCode** on a **Macbook**, and this is how I got it to work...

As [John Pankowicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978840/john-pankowicz) mentioned, you can add your connections directly into the settings.json file which lives in your .vscode folder (user profile or workspace level).

On my **Mac**, I must specify the **protocol** to use for connecting to the SQL Server on our domain, which in my case, is **tcp**.

Also, you may specify a **profileName** for each of your database connections if your server names are very cryptic and difficult to remember.

So an entry in my **settings.json** looks like this:

```
"mssql.connections": [
    {
        "profileName": "FOOBARDEV",
        "authenticationType": "Integrated",
        "trustServerCertificate": true,
        "server": "tcp:foosql28.foobar.com\\edsql281,581"
    }]
```

Once defined, the connection appears in the VsCode sidebar within the CONNECTIONS section of the SQL Server extension listed by profile name.

[image]

Alternatively, you can define an **ADO.NET** connection string:

```
"mssql.connections": [
{
    "profileName": "FOOBARDEV",
    "connectionString": "data source=tcp:foosql28.foobar.com\\edsql281,581;Integrated Security=True;initial catalog=Foo; Trust Server Certificate=True"
}]
```

Comment: Hey Daniel. Just curious if a connection to a LocalDB or localhost mssql server is possible on mac? SQL Server itself would need to be made available for Mac in order for this to be possible, correct? Asking because want to check if I configured the extension correctly as I do not have access to a remote mssql server yet.

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, you are using LocalDb,
add this to your User settings.json file in VsCode:

```
"mssql.connections": [
    {
      "server": "(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb",
      "database": "YourDatabaseName",
      "authenticationType": "Integrated",
      "profileName": "YourProfileName",
      "password": ""
    }
  ]
```

"YourProfileName" is anything you want. It shows up in Object Explorer.